# SharedPreferences in fragment?

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, sharedpreferences

i want have to fragment and in database i set a column for loginStatus by default its signout but when he sign in change to sign in and save in app the user sign in ...
how can i do this with sharedpreferences to keep sign in user in application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("isSignIn", "Yes");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use sharedPreferences, you can update the column from signout to signin directly in you database.

Comment: for example i have 1000 user how can i know who sign in and who sign out and then show the correct profile to the user?

Comment: I'm not understanding, you have a database inside or outside your android application? The 1000 users, are stored in the application room database?

Comment: i have sql database outside application, but i cant understand how can do this ?

Comment: If your application has to edit your sql database, you have to create a rest api in a server, connect the server to your sql database, and from your app call an api of your's to edit the entries on your database